# Salesforce Validation

Tags: php, salesforce

I have to prevent my salesforce account from bots. I am trying set a validation rule in salesforce server side to check my hidden field from my submitting form. Any one please help me to set validation rule in sales force server to compare the hidden field value with my string.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I put a hidden text field with value "Yes". I plan to set the validation rule in salesforce account to check the value of my form's hidden field. If the value is "Yes" , i have to allow the form. Otherwise the form should show error msg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tagged the question as php & salesforce so I assume you have some kind of PHP frontend page that's talking to Salesforce in the background?

In that case I think you're doing it wrong.

Try to stop the spammers as soon as you can - in your PHP. Communication to SF, validation there and coming back will be just a waste of CPU cycles and network traffic. Implement reCAPTCHA or maybe simply add this hidden field in PHP form... I think it would be best if you'll be adding this field via javascript (bots have trouble evaluating JS), if the field is not present & doesn't have your expected value - block the page submission.

Bonus points for making the expected value random, using session/cookies... hell, there must be tons of reading material about simple bot protection in PHP ;)

That way your PHP is your only gateway, you don't even need a new field in salesforce. But if you insist - simplest validation rule would be

```
MyCustomField__c != 'Yes'
```

If you were unable to come up with such solution you have a lot of reading about SF configuration ahead of you...

If you have one dedicated user whose credentials are stored in the PHP script you might decide to apply this rule only to this particular user and not pester the regular SF users. In that case something like this will do the trick.

```
CONTAINS($User.Username, 'integration.user@example.com') && MyCustomField__c != 'Yes'
```

Answer (score -1):

for add an OR here. Otherwise the picklist would have to have both values at the same time, in order to evaluate to true..

```
AND(
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > DATE(2012,8,23),
AND(
OR(
ISPICKVAL( CCI_Division_Region__c , "CCI Networks"),
ISPICKVAL( CCI_Division_Region__c , "CCI Distribution")),
OR(
AND(Services__c > 0,
ISBLANK(TEXT(Product__c )),
ISBLANK(Services_Product_Involved__c)),
AND(Support__c > 0,
ISBLANK(Support_Provider__c)),
AND(Product__c > 0,
ISBLANK(TEXT(Product_Manufacturer__c))))))
for more salesforce validation rules and regulation you can follow this given link. http://alturl.com/8ouz8
```